# How to make a fixed navbar respect the responsive height of a responsive div space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div space at the top of my page that holds a logo and a tagline. Directly underneath it is a responsive fixed navbar (twitter bootstrap 3). When my window is minimized, the top div becomes responsive and increases it's height, but the fixed navbar below it does not respect it's increase in height (and stays in the same place).

How can I get the fixed navbar to allow the top div to allow it's height increase space?

This is what is happening:

[image]

```
   <div class="welcometop" >

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1"><a href="/"><img src="/images/citylightslogo.png" alt="logo"  id="cllogo"/></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
     <h1 id="headline33" > 100% Satisfaction Guaranteed!</h1><h1 id="headline24" > Call Anytime! (888) 777-6666 </h1>
           </div>

       </div> 
      </div>
     </div> <!-- Close Welcome Top -->


    <div class=" navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
      <nav role="navigation">
       <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#midnav">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
        </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="midnav">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/office.html">Office</a></li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="h/">Find us on Angie's List</a></li>
 <li><a href="/>Yelp</a></li>

     </ul>
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
   </nav>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-default -->
```

Comment: Show us your code please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shm2y/ but I can't get the image in their as a logo for some reason....

Answer (score 2):

Do not give any top value. In [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top), `top:0;` is given. To override it use

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: auto;
}
```

Hence your fixed navbar will always stay just below `.welcometop` div.

To make `.welcometop` and `.navbar` fixed at top try somthing like below.

```
<div class="welcometop affix" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- codes for top area of navbar -->
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- codes for navbar -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: remove `.navbar-fixed-top` class from `.navbar`. Add `.affix` to `.welcometop`

Comment: Hi @Iqbal, I applied a padding-top of 200px to the body to account for the fixed div with a 200px height at top...how do I account for that as well when the height increases from being responsive ( I think that is my problem)?

Comment: I think for your case this is not necessary to give top padding to the `body`. To ensure that contents after **fixed nav** not hiding below **nav**, just add top `padding`/`margin` to the content next to **fixed nav**.

Comment: Not putting a padding:top of the height of the fixed div at the top to the body makes all of the body content hide behind the top fixed div

Comment: I told before, "for your case this is not necessary to give top padding to the body"

Comment: Right, and I am saying that giving top padding to the body appears to be the only way to get the mid navbar below my top fixed content

Comment: Hmm, so `.welcometop` is also fixed positioned, right? I that case, group `.welcometop` and `navbar` in a fixed positined div. I have edited my answer, so you will understand what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a `position: fixed` for the navbar, you'll have :

- either to add a margin-top (or padding-top) to your content of the same height than the navbar,
- or to create a void div below (= with a lower z-index) the navbar of the same height with a `position: relative` or no defined position (= `inherit`).

EDIT : I forgot, in case your content has a position absolute, fixed of static, you'll obviously have to manage the `top` css property of the content.

Comment: I understand that's what you would have to do in a normal case, but I am looking to just allow the fixed navbar to change location based on the increase in the top div